# Type androidx.appcompat.resources.R$dimen is defined multiple times

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

We have a React Native app where after upgrading to Android Studio 3.6.1 and Gradle plugin 3.6.1 we are seeing this compilation error:

```
Type androidx.appcompat.resources.R$dimen is defined multiple times: /Users/andrew/Software/project/android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/productionRelease/out/androidx/appcompat/resources/R$dimen.dex, /Users/andrew/Software/project/android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/productionRelease/out/15bdf8225afad69777cd7f9bd328ab094900c8289014e0107b56c5c62099dfea_3.jar:classes.dex
```

Here are our dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@dblackker/cameraroll": "^1.3.4",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.7.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.0.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^6.2.0",
    "appcenter": "^2.6.1",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^2.6.1",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^2.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "clone": "^2.1.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "memoize-one": "^5.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-custom-validation": "^0.5.7",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-add-calendar-event": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^5.0.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-heic-converter": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.7.4",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.6.1",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "^0.0.21",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-section-list-get-item-layout": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-share": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.12.0",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.6",
    "react-navigation": "3.12.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.11.2",
    "validator": "^10.8.0"
  }
```

Can anyone help figure out what the issue is, and how could we debug this type of issue in the future?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same error after upgrading to 3.6.1! If you find anything please let me know. I'm stuck :(

Comment: Solved by downgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 3.5.0 and Gradle Version to 5.5!

Comment: Same issue, but downgrading to 3.5.0 brings other issues. This appeared literally out of nowhere. After downgrading, upgrading again worked for me. Perhaps something to do with caches...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Igor Montella's comment to my question fixed the problem - downgrade to gradle plugin 3.5.0.

Comment: Downgrading vital tools for the IDE should never be a permanent solution. This only covers up the real problem.

Comment: Of course I would prefer to not downgrade. However when using a framework like React Native that is so heavily dependent on third party libraries, I often have little choice if I want to continue development.

Answer (score 38):

Got the same problem, just clean project and rebuild again.

Comment: For those who do not how to clean the project, simply type: `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: Thanks, I made it and work well ...

Answer (score 12):

I deleted `android/app/build` folder, because my duplicates were exactly there.

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue after updating gradle version to 3.6.3 from 3.5.2 in Android Studio.

I have multiple Build Variants.

I fixed the issue by first deleting .gradle folder from the project and did Clean Project and Rebuild Project.

If you have multiple build variant you may have to do same thing for each one when you change build variants from one to another.

Answer (score 3):

I just run following built in routine in **Android Studio:**

- File > Sync Project with Gradle Files

And then it worked again :-)

Answer (score 3):

While I was coding on the android studio on native android.Got the same problem

> Type androidx.appcompat.resources.R$dimen is defined multiple times:

The problem is because of the **Duplication of the BuildConfig** which is present inside the **JAVA (Generated) Directory**

Here is the solution to fix the problem.

You have to delete the **duplicate BuildConfig** from the android studio by this process

1. Click on **java(generated)** on the Left side

[image]

2. The problem is extra Build Config Created

[image]

3. When you click any of the BuildConfig, it will show the same error display in the picture

[image]

4. Delete the extra BuildConfig and keep the original BuildConfig.

**Problem Solved**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Googlers:
In my case, I've created a benchmark module (with `plugin "com.android.library"`) and made it depend on the app module (with `plugin "com.android.application"`). 
But library module can not depend on the application module, as Gradle does not support it.
Here some info:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/boi4xg/modularization_help_android_library_module/

Answer (score 2):

My errors were similar, with a "is defined multiple times" message.

I solved it by downgrading the Gradle plugin to 3.5.0, running the app — or at least trying to — then upgrading to Gradle plugin 3.6.2 again.

I am not sure why, but this seemed to have cleared some caches or dependencies I was not aware of.

Removing `~/.gradle` or `android/.gradle` did *not* help.

Comment: I did not get my Android project running again by downgrading to 3.5.0 and than back to 3.6.2. But I got it running by just downgrading to 3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to follow**

1. Sync gradle files
2. go to build section --> clean Project
3. go to build section --> rebuild Project
4. Again Sync the gradle files

Note: Make sure your PC/ Laptop connect with internet
and updated android studio

Answer (score 0):

File->Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `~/.gradle/caches`

seems to work good. I did this because I saw `~/.gradle/caches` in my error.

```
Type androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate is defined multiple times:
/Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/08344aeb2253f0dce062ee9436d14235/transformed/legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex,
/Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bde9e50d97f78024fdfcb4b5869842c8/transformed/legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0-runtime/classes.dex
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all outdated. I used 4.1.2. If you look at the path given in AS, it should point to \app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\debug\out. Go to this path, delete all the *.jar files, leaving the most recent one. I tried this and my project worked perfectly.

Don't bother with invalidates caches / restart as it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same issue
in my case
simply You have upgrade dependency it also works for me

Answer (score 0):

@Wito Divaro, his answer helped me. If you are bothered by "R is defined multiple times.", just try to get rid of 'android/app/build'.
Furthermore, I added this below line to app/build.gradle.
If you want to try, try this.

```
defaultConfig {
   ..............
   multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    ..............
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    ..............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, that fixed it.

step 1: I deleted the file BuildConfig in: app->java(generated)->BuildConfig

step 2: Clean Project: Build->Clean Project

step 3: Build->Rebuild Project

Answer (score -1):

**I faced the same problem and solved it simply follow the above path and delete all files**

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @husseinkhalaf your answer is incomplete, you forgot to add the **path**, which is supposed to be deleted!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: You have to delete all files in a folder
release and then clean project