# Type androidx.activity.R$drawable is defined multiple times:

Tags: android, kotlin, adk

When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

Type androidx.activity.R$drawable is defined multiple times: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\Quizzaria\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\debug\out\2f1abb1bf059eed68381ee1f8abbd335bb11b5d842853a70e5bc1943c6dbde23_0.jar:classes.dex, C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\Quizzaria\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\debug\out\9af8cb4894b642ee0bf9af510aa81fc1bbe550d01ed87af8f91c58876cd6c749_0.jar:classes.dex

Comment: You probably  need to clean and rebuild your app. You can android's studio build menu for that

Comment: It seems like the same issue was fixed by this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60784432/7707187

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem. I went to the indicated directory in the text above and deleted old files. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the build folder from android->app->build
sync the project i hope this will help.